# Updating SVN remotely via batch file

Tags: batch-file, remoting

I tried searching relevant threads, it didn't worked. So here are the detailed question / situation, where I am looking for help.

1. I have 30 client nodes where I have setup SVN and checked out two folders (which needs to be updated) exactly when I want (forcefully).. e.g : "d:\gbv\textures" and "d:\gbv\characters"
2. then I put svnUpdate.bat file in main d: drive with relevant command e.g: "svn update blabla"
3. if I run this bat file by double clicking, it works fine ( it updates )
4. now I thought, I should create a batch file, where I type all 30 nodes IP, and set of commands, to run that batch file from local d: and it should work.
5. PROBLEM: I am unable to do this.

   - because I am unable to do this, from my cmd panel.
   - because I am not sure, how I can access network pc and tell it to run "d:\svnUpdate.bat" from its drive from dos prompt. ( obviously, I can do this via win explorer visually ).

Hopefully the question will make sense.

Comment: thanks, i tested it yesterday. everything is working fine. its really helpful. no rendernode (clientside) tweaking required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute files on remote machines in a network using [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553). I use it to execute batch files and pass parameters to them.

You'll probably need the `-w` option to set the working directory.

Of course this is a lot easier with powershell remoting, but since you already set it up with batch, PsExec works fine.